# Why does GCC give an unexpected result when adding float values?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I'm using GCC to compile a program which adds floats, longs, ints and chars. When it runs, the result is bad. The following program unexpectedly prints the value of 34032.101562.

Recompiling with a Microsoft compiler gives the right result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    const char val_c = 10;
    const int val_i = 20;
    const long val_l = 34000;
    const float val_f = 2.1;

    float result;
    result = val_c + val_i + val_l + val_f;

    printf("%f\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb to remember is that an IEEE-754 single-precision float can store about 7 decimal places of precision.  If you look at your result, it contains exactly 7 correct digits: 3403210 (the decimal point doesn't count).  The fact that the answer diverges after seven decimal places shouldn't be surprising, nor should it be surprising that different compilers give different results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What do you think the "right result" is?  I'm guessing that you believe it is 34032.1.  It isn't.

2.1 is not representable as a `float`, so `val_f` instead is initialized with the closest representable `float` value.  In binary, 2.1 is:

```
10.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001...
```

a `float` has 24 binary digits, so the value of `val_f` in binary is:

```
10.0001100110011001100110
```

The expression `resultat = val_c + val_i + val_l + val_f` computes `34030 + val_f`, which is evaluated in single-precision and causes another rounding to occur.

```
  1000010011101110.0
+               10.0001100110011001100110
-----------------------------------------
  1000010011110000.0001100110011001100110
rounds to 24 digits:
-----------------------------------------
  1000010011110000.00011010
```

In decimal, this result is exactly 34032.1015625.  Because the `%f` format prints 6 digits after the decimal point (unless specified otherwise), this is rounded again, and printf prints `34032.101562`.

Now, why do you not get this result when you compile with MSVC?  The C and C++ standard allow floating-point calculations to be carried out in a wider type if the compiler chooses to do so.  MSVC does this with your calculation, which means that the result of `34030 + val_f` is not rounded before being passed to `printf`.  In that case, the exact floating-point value being printed is 34032.099999999991268850862979888916015625, which is rounded to 34032.1 by printf.

Why don't all compilers do what MSVC does?  A few reasons.  First, it's slower on some processors.  Second, and more importantly, although it can give more accurate answers, the programmer cannot depend on that -- seemingly unrelated code changes can cause the answer to change in the presence of this behavior.  Because of this, carrying extra precision often causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @light: I added an explanation of MSVC's behavior to my answer.

Comment: @Stephen: I assume you did not calculate the bits and the exact values manually (or did you? If so: respect!). What app or web app did you use to do this? Could be very useful for an article I am writing.

Comment: @Rudy: I tend to do them using integer computations in python, sorry.

Comment: @Stephen: OK, I guess I could do the same. Thanks! Hmmm... how did you get the exact value for the MSVC part? Does Python allow arbitrary precision?

Comment: The MSVC value happens to be representable in double, so you can print it from python.  Python uses the host system's `printf` to print doubles, so you can print as many digits as your system supports.  On OS X (and Linux, I think) you can get python to print 64 digits using "%0.64f" % value.

Answer (score 2):

Google David Goldberg's paper "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic".

Answer (score 1):

The **float** format has only about 6-7 digits of precision. Use **%7.1f** or some other reasonable format and you will like your results better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here. 2.1 has no exact representation in IEEE floating-point format, and as such, it is converting the entire answer to a floating-point number with around 6-7 (correct) sig-figs. If you need more precision, use a double.